# How to follow symlinks for which output?

Tags: bash, command-line-interface, ls

I have this handy function for showing symlinks from the `which` command.

```
function whichl() {
    ls -la $(which -a $@)
}
```

It works great for things that are symlinked from the path, like python.

```
$ whichl python
-rwxr-xr-x  1 root  wheel  66880 Mar 27 23:02 /usr/bin/python
lrwxr-xr-x  1 me    admin     43 Dec 19  2017 /usr/local/bin/python -> /usr/local/Cellar/python/2.7.14/bin/python2

$ ls -la $(which -a python3)
lrwxr-xr-x  1 me    admin  34 Jun  8 10:42 /usr/local/bin/python3 -> ../Cellar/python/3.6.5/bin/python3
```

It does not work so great when `which` doesn't find anything; the `ls -la` command runs against the current directory. This has confused me for the last time!

So, looking for two answers here.

1. Is there a better way to get `which` results to show symlinks?
   I'm on OS X (if it wasn't obvious) and `man which` says my version is BSD December 13, 2006.
2. What is the best way to get my helper function to halt on when `which` returns no results? I've confirmed the return code in this case is `1`, but a simple `set -e` doesn't change the behavior.

Comment: *"but a simple `set -e` doesn't change the behavior."* -- you call `set -e` in the current shell (where the function runs) but `which` is executed in a subshell (because of `$(...)`). You can store the value produced by `$(which -a $@)` in a variable and run `ls -la` only when it is not empty.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As I mentioned in the question, this doesn't work:

```
function whichl() {
    set -e
    ls -la $(which -a $@)
}
```

The explanation from the comments:

> You call `set -e` in the current shell (where the function runs) but which is executed in a subshell (because of `$(...)`). You can store the value produced by $(which -a $@) in a variable and run ls -la only when it is not empty.

Following that suggestion, this is what I arrived at.

```
function whichl() {
    RESULT=$(which -a $@)
    if [ -z "$RESULT" ]; then
        echo "No results for \"$@\""
        return 1
    fi
    ls -la -- ${RESULT}
}
```

And it works perfectly from all I can test right now!

```
$ whichl python python3
-rwxr-xr-x  1 root  wheel  66880 Mar 27 23:02 /usr/bin/python
lrwxr-xr-x  1 me    admin     43 Dec 19  2017 /usr/local/bin/python -> /usr/local/Cellar/python/2.7.14/bin/python2
lrwxr-xr-x  1 me    admin     34 Jun  8 10:42 /usr/local/bin/python3 -> ../Cellar/python/3.6.5/bin/python3
```

Notice it returns 3 results from 2 inputs, the system `python` and brew `python`.

```
$ whichl foo bar
No results for "foo bar"
```